# Elixir heredocs closing triple quotes (""") behavior

Tags: elixir

I noticed that the following two calls produce a different result string:

```
# Closing quotes not indented
"""
 a
"""

# Closing quotes indented
"""
 a
 """
```

The first call will return `" a\n"`, while the second one returns `a\n`.

It seems as if the indentation level of the closing quotes indicate a point up until the leading whitespace is truncated for every line in the heredoc. If you have 8 leading whitespaces and an ending quote indentation of 4 you would end up with 4 leading whitespaces in the resulting string. Characters and everything after the first actual character is not truncated.

I did not find any documentation on that behavior in the Elixir docs. Is it a bug?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I did not find any documentation about this but this definitely intentional as a commit with subject

> Allow heredocs to be aligned according to the position the heredoc end.

was [committed by José Valim on 20 Feb 2012](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/commit/1c98392b96c9116710508fc26727d1cd5e215331) and it includes a new function in `elixir_tokenizer` with the comment:

```
%% Remove spaces from heredoc based on the position of the final quotes.
```

and a test case similar to the one you wrote in the question:

```
test :double_quoted_aligned_heredoc do
  assert_equal "foo\nbar\nbar\n", """ <> "bar\n"
  foo
  bar
  """
end
```

Comment: Good to know, that confused me a bit ;-)